# I tried so many methods but still can't find the slideshow button on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, slideshow

I've found a few approaches here and tried each of them, but still can't find the missing button, can someone help?

I'm currently managing Jupyter with anaconda

[image]

```
conda install nb_conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\....\anaconda3\envs\workEnv-python3.7

  added / updated specs:
    - nb_conda


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  nb_conda           pkgs/main/win-64::nb_conda-2.2.1-py37_0
  nb_conda_kernels   pkgs/main/win-64::nb_conda_kernels-2.2.2-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | b'Enabling nb_conda_kernels...\nStatus: enabled\n'
- b'Enabling notebook extension nb_conda/main...\n      - Validating: ok\nEnabling tree extension nb_conda/tree...\n      - Validating: ok\nEnabling: nb_conda\n- Writing config: C:\\Users\\....\\anaconda3\\envs\\workEnv-python3.7\\etc\\jupyter\n    - Validating...\n      nb_conda 2.2.1 ok\n'
done
```

Comment: Can you link to a reference concerning the button you are looking for?

Comment: @Wayne 'Using RISE for a SlideShow' http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/09/25/creating-presentations-with-jupyter-notebook/

Comment: Follow install at https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html.

Comment: You can get a sense of how things should look by using `launch binder` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-rise). If you use exit to leave slideshow, you’ll see buttons. Note that is using old version as cand see by use of `damianvila82` in `environment.yml`. Try conda-forge first.